# Find and extract cells containing more than one entry

Tags: matlab, cell

**Problem**

I have a cell array 1x15350 and I want to find every cell that contains more than one value, hence is bigger then 1x1.

For example:

```
A={{1}, {2 3}, {4}}

A = 

{1x1 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x1 cell}
```

**Question**

How can I extract the only the cells that are bigger then `1x1 cell`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

Use the following approach:

```
out = A(cellfun(@numel,A)>1);
```

**Result**

I ran the following script:

```
A={{1}, {2 3}, {4}};
B={{1}, {2 3}, {4},{9,2,1},{8}};
outA = A(cellfun(@numel,A)>1);
outB = B(cellfun(@numel,B)>1);
```

And got these results:

```
outA = 

{1x2 cell}


outB = 

{1x2 cell}    {1x3 cell}

outA{1} =

[2]    [3]
```

Comment: cellfun has an option that mimics @numel but is much faster. It is called 'prodofsize'. For a cell array c with 10000 elements: `>> tic, for i = 1:1000, y=cellfun(@numel,c); end, toc
Elapsed time is 10.050336 seconds.
>> tic, for i = 1:1000, y=cellfun('prodofsize',c); end, toc
Elapsed time is 0.073865 seconds.
>> all(cellfun('prodofsize', c) == cellfun(@numel, c))

ans =

     1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A(cellfun(@numel,A)==1) = []
```

Comment: It's always better to add an explanation to the code you're posting as an answer, so that it will helps visitors understand why this is a good answer.